# Symfony 4.4 getRepository No Longer Working

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I recently updated a Symfony app to 4.4 from 4.2 and now my getRepository calls no longer work.

I was calling getting my repos like this:

```
$oems = $em->getRepository('App:OEM')->findAll();
```

After reading about the issue I changed to this:

```
$oems = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(OEM::class)->findAll();
```

But now I get this error:

> Class "App\Controller\OEM" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I wasn't including the class. Added this and it worked:

```
use App\Entity\OEM;
```